# Python prints if statement, and not the elif statement, regardless of input

Tags: python, if-statement

Python is, for some reason printing my if statement regardless of input, even when the statement is false.

````
 print("Treasure Quest")  
 print("------------")  
  
 name = input("What is your name traveler?") 
 print("Your game name for this game is: " + name+"")
  
  
 goldCoin = ("Take this  gold coin, it's rare!")  
 ans1 = input("Will you take the coin? Yes or No?")
 if ans1 == 'Yes' or 'Y':
  print("You have gained 1 point")
 elif ans1 == 'No' or 'N':
    print(" You have chosen to leave the coin.")
    print("You did not gain a point.")```
````

Comment: Why is goldCoin just a tuple with a str in it? Did you mean to print it?

Comment: @TommyA. It's a string, not a tuple although the brackets are redundant.

Comment: @TommyA. That's actually just a string for reference. It would need a trailing `,` to be a tuple.

Comment: i've tried the in block as suggested, but now when I type N or no, nothing prints, it skips to the next line